# R programming- adding column in dataset error

Tags: r

```
cv.uk.df$new.d[2:nrow(cv.uk.df)] <- tail(cv.uk.df$deaths, -1) - head(cv.uk.df$deaths, -1) # this line of code works
```

I wanted to know why do we -1 in the tail and  -1 in head to create this new column.

I made an effort to understand by removing the -1 and "R"(The code is in R studio) throws me this error.

Could anyone shed some light on this? I can't explain how much I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please use the code formatting markup (4 spaces) to make code examples readable. Moreover, the error from R studio is ommitted in your question.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to help. I can't thank you enough, kind of new to the ropes here. Sorry for not including the R error. I thought I did. I think the solution has been laid out below. Cheers @cdalitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what is being done. On the left-hand side of the assignment operator, we have:

```
cv.uk.df$new.d[2:nrow(cv.uk.df)] <-
```

Let's pick this apart.

```
cv.uk.df   # This is the data.frame
$new.d     # a new column to assign or a column to reassign 
[2:nrow(cv.uk.df)] # the rows which we are going to assign
```

Specifically, this line of code will assign a new value all rows of this column except the first. Why would we want to do that? We don't have your data, but from your example, it looks like you want to calculate the change from one line to the next. That calculation is invalid for the first row (no previous row).

Now let's look at the right-hand side.

```
<- tail(cv.uk.df$deaths, -1) - head(cv.uk.df$deaths, -1)
```

The `cv.uk.df$deaths` column has the same number of rows as the data.frame. R gets grouchy when the numbers of elements don't follow sum rules. For data.frames, the right-hand side needs to have the same number of elements, or a number that can be recycled a whole-number of times. For example, if you have 10 rows, you need to have a replacement of 10 values. Or you can have 5 values that R will recycle.

If your data.frame has 100 rows, only 99 are being replaced in this operation. You cannot feed 100 values into an operation that expects 99. We need to trim the data. Let's look at what is happening. The `tail()` function has the usage `tail(x, n)`, where it returns the last `n` values of `x`. If `n` is a negative integer, `tail()` returns all values but the first `n`. The `head()` function works similarly.

```
tail(cv.uk.df$deaths, -1)  # This returns all values but the first 
head(cv.uk.df$deaths, -1)  # This returns all values but the last
```

This makes sense for your calculation. You cannot subtract the number of deaths in the row before the first row from the number in the first row, nor can you subtract the number of deaths in the last row from the number in the row after the last row. There are more intuitive ways to do this thing using functions from other packages, but this gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ben, that was helpful. Cheers!!!